# What exactly were the three signs alluded to in the "Signs" (2002) trailer and teasers?

Tags: signs

In the trailer, and various TV spots, it was [mentioned](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286106/taglines/):

> The first sign you can't explain. The second sign you can't ignore. The third sign you won't believe.

It seems obvious that the first sign is the crop circles, but what are the other two signs?

Comment: A good question. I've taken the liberty of tidying it up a little and putting the quote into quote marks using >